# Facebook page ownership got claimed by someone that is not the owner

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am a small business owner and a couple of years ago I created a Facebook page for my business.

Over the years I started working together with an artist. He posts some work related content on his Instagram and thought that if he linked the Facebook page to it that it would create traffic by forwarding people to the Facebook page.

What happened however is that resulted in him "claiming" page ownership. Both of us can't see an option to revert this or to make me page owner since the company is on my name and I have the official papers for it.

Does anyone have a clue how I should continue? Removing the page to create a new one is not an option. 
I tried business.facebook however it also says in there that he is the page owner and therefor I can't do anything. He however doesn't seem to have the company page in the interface so I can't find an option on his account to remove ownership of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was such a long drag, but I have found the solution.

Long story short, he had to remove the page from his business account for it to become "unclaimed" after which I claimed it with the actual business account.